# Firebase Cloud Function is performing super slow compared to local response time

Tags: javascript, performance, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I’ve just deployed a cloud function to my Firebase project (free tier).

Here's a minimal version of the code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Fuse = require('fuse.js');
const _ = require('lodash');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.minimal = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  let category = request.query.cat ? request.query.cat.toLowerCase().trim() : undefined;
  let classification = request.query.class ? request.query.class.toLowerCase().trim() : undefined;
  let catName, className;

  return admin.database().ref('categories').once('value').then(snapshot => {

    _.each(snapshot.val(), (value, key) => {

      _.each(value, (value2, key2) => {

        if ( key2 === 'id' && value2 == category ) catName = key;
        else if ( value2.id == classification ) className = key2;

      });

    });

    return _.split(request.query.q, ',');

  })
  .then(literals => {

    return admin.database().ref(`mappings/${catName}/${className}`).once('value').then(snapshot => {

      let mappings = _.map(snapshot.val(), (value, key) => {

        return {
          literal: key,
          code: value
        };

      });

      const options = {
        shouldSort: true,
        includeScore: true,
        threshold: 0.3,
        location: 0,
        distance: 50,
        maximumPatternLength: 64,
        minMatchCharacterLength: 1,
        keys: ["literal"]
      };

      let fuse = new Fuse(mappings, options);
      let results = {};
      let classCodes = {};

      _.each(literals, literal => {

        let searchResults = fuse.search(literal);

        if ( ! searchResults.length ) {

          results[literal] = { status: 'not-matched' };

        }
        else {

          if ( ! classCodes[searchResults[0].item.code] ) {

            classCodes[searchResults[0].item.code] = { code: searchResults[0].item.code, standard: '' };

          }

          results[literal] = {

            status: 'matched',
            mapping: classCodes[searchResults[0].item.code]

          };

        }

      });

      return admin.database().ref(`classification-systems/${catName}/${className}`).once('value').then(snapshot => {

        _.each(snapshot.val(), (value, key) => {

          if ( classCodes[key] ) classCodes[key].standard = value;

        });

        response.json(results);

      });

    });

  })
  .catch(error => { // Never gets triggered

    if ( ! response._headerSent ) response.json(error)
    else console.error(error);

  });

});
```

I was running it locally (but all database operations were performing on the live database) and the average response time for 100 words searched in 2000+ keys in the database was 1.5 seconds.

Running the same test code on the deployed function resulted in the average response time of 45 seconds!!!

Why is the live cloud function performing so poorly?

Is there anyway to achieve the same response time as the local function? The current response time is insanely unacceptable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing code, there's not a whole lot of advice that can be given.  You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: The output is the same, the code is not changed at all when it was running locally, and all local operations were using the actual database, the code doesn’t send any requests to external resources. It just basically searches in the database. No errors are thrown, and I followed the best practices shown in Firebase documentation. Running the same code locally still has the 1.5s response time. The database is also accessed through firebase-admin. I really can’t show the actual code, but is it just me? Or has this happened to others?

Comment: If you're looking for a conversation, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to post.  Consider posting to firebase-talk or using the Firebase slack instead. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk http://firebase.community/

Comment: Also, I’ve used lodash instead of the built-in functions like map, filter, and forEach.

Comment: @DougStevenson Not looking for a conversation, just asking if this is a pattern with Cloud Functions and if it has anything to do with the pricing plans.

Comment: There is no difference between the performance of Cloud Functions based on pricing plans. But as Doug said, without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful) it'll be hard to say what causes the difference.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the question with a minimal version of my code. The same exact problem as before. Performs really well locally but poorly when deployed.

Comment: @DougStevenson Would you please take a look at my code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Does this log have any effects on the performance? Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

Comment: So you're on the free Spark plan and not the Blaze plan with billing enabled?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that’s true, haven’t enabled billing and I’m using the spark plan. Would it make a big difference to switch?

Comment: Whether your project is paid or not makes no difference on performance.

Comment: So what could be the problem here? Is it something I’m doing wrong?

Comment: The code in itself looks good. But it's hard to say whether the function is CPU bound, network I/O bound, disk I/O bound, or memory bound. All of these are going to be very different in the Cloud Functions than on your own local system. If it's memory bound, you could try increasing the memory size of your Cloud Functions container.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is that only possible with upgrading to a better plan? Or can I configure my instances in the dashboard somewhere?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The detailed usage stats says: Memory Allocated: 256MB and Timeout: 60 seconds (I'm afraid that the function would timeout if I increase my input slightly since the current input takes 45 seconds, this is a real issue for me)

Comment: Your first step should be to determine what the constraining factor is: CPU, Network, Disk, or Memory. If the code is memory bound, you can consider upgrading the container to provide more memory (at a higher cost). I don't think CPU can be upgraded, so if the problem is CPU bound you may be out of luck.

Comment: I've been having the same problem with a project I'm using a cloud function that gets data from firebase database.  I've tried using RTDB and cloud firestore with similar results.  Works very fast locally but takes 10 seconds once deployed.  Did you figure anything out? @RamtinSoltani ?

Comment: @mattc19 I gave up after a while. Firebase is awesome and has many amazing products bundled together, but the Cloud Functions at its current stage is not one of them. Though to be honest my code required a little bit of CPU, so I think having it running as a Cloud Function was not a good idea. I ended up using a free AWS EC2 instance instead (not even a Lambda). With that said, Cloud Functions can be useful as a bridge between other Firebase products and also for running small code that does not require intense resources, but it should not be used when an actual server is more appropriate.